# How to overlay items in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I tried to place items which contains `ImageView` in screen. Like picture.

Item count is below 10 (0 to 10) And it will be send from server.

I consider use `RecyclerView` ,`StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and `ItemDecoration`'s `getItemOffsets` method.

But I'm not sure its good idea.

Is any great solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want this images to be static size on screen?

Comment: How about design some layouts that contain some images and the images are overlay each other. and show them in one recyclerview item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recycler view does not provide overlay functionality.

But As @Zachary Sweigart said you can add 10 different imageviews inside relative layout. But if in long-term these items increase from 10 to 20 and you want to provide scrolling functionality for it. That time it will become difficult to manage 20 imageviews. For that, we have to design custom Recyclerview which will provide overlay image functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only up to 10 items and no scrolling is necessary you can just use a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: You mean make 10 `ImageView` in layout xml?

Comment: Or create the views programmatically and add the to the recycler view